# Highlight colors in Xcode's project navigator

Tags: xcode

I have the hardest time navigating the file structure in Xcode projects.  One feature that I feel strongly would help me is the ability to add custom highlight colors to different filenames in Xcode's project navigator.

I imagine it's possible since Xcode will highlight the text area of the current file you're working on, and it will also change the font color to be red if a file is not detected in your project.  (Also a "Favorites" or "Recent Items" section would be a.w.e.s.o.m.e)

Apple used to allow for folder and file colors in their finder.  Unfortunately, now they only allow color labels in the form of little colored dots next to a file, instead of actually changing the text area color itself.  I loved this feature, it helped me find what I needed and it significantly decreased the time I spent navigating to find files.

Does this exist/ is there a plugin/ where are these preferences set/ is there a hacky workaround to implement this? I'm willing to go any route.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is there really no solution?